# I need a contact submit form fixed

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I have the modal toggling, that is easy with bootstrap. But now, whenever I click submit the form gets redirected to php/contact-process.php. It looks like the php is processed but then just stays at a white screen, and not being redirected and no email is received to my main email(i put example@gmail.com for stackexchange question). Please help me.

```
<!--Modals for Contact-->
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role = "dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">

      <form class="form-horizontal contact" name="contact" action="php/contact-process.php">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4>Contact Us</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contact-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <textarea name="usertext" name="message" id=""  rows="8" class="form-control" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send!">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CONTACT-PROCESS.PHP:

```
<?php
//add the recipient's address here
$myemail = 'example@gmail.com';

//grab named inputs from html then post to #thanks
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

//generate email and send!
$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Message \n $message";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

//redirect
header("Location: index.php");

exit();
} 
?>
```

Comment: A white screen could easily mean an unreported error.  Check the PHP and web server logs, turn on error reporting, etc.

Comment: Is your mail relay hanging or the server incorrectly defined? I've seen something similar in .NET when an email can't be sent. It'll drive you batty because it won't return an error until you timeout. Could also be your mail relay needs a login or something.

Comment: Side security note: It looks like you're leaving yourself open to [e-mail injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection) by allowing not-fully-sanitized user input into your mail headers.

Comment: I will clean and sanitize the form but I am just going crazy since I do have error reporting on but I get no errors.